Can't complete the deployment of contract to the Polygon Testnet Amoy
I have been trying my best to deploy to the Polygon Amoy testnet, but with no vain. I'm using Hardhat ignition modules to deploy to the testnet. I have 0.4 POL on the amoy testnet wallet. I got the link to the network from Alchemy. The link with API key is working fine, tested using Postman. The following is the deploy.js file:
const { buildModule } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/modules");

var erccontract = ""

module.exports = buildModule("erc721contract", (m) => {
  erccontract = m.contract("erc721");
  return { erccontract };
});

console.log("Contract Deployed at address: ",erccontract);

The following is the output of the future variable erccontract that deals with the contract to be deployed:
Contract Deployed at address:  <ref *1> NamedContractDeploymentFutureImplementation {
  id: 'erc721contract#erc721',
  type: 'NAMED_ARTIFACT_CONTRACT_DEPLOYMENT',
  module: IgnitionModuleImplementation {
    id: 'erc721contract',
    results: { erccontract: [Circular *1] },
    futures: Set(1) { [Circular *1] },
    submodules: Set(0) {}
  },
  dependencies: Set(0) {},
  contractName: 'erc721',
  constructorArgs: [],
  libraries: {},
  value: 0n,
  from: undefined
}

As you can see here, the contract is not fully deployed, because the from address is undefined. I'm also sharing my hardhat.config.js file:
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

require("dotenv").config();

const { NEW_API_URL_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.20",
  defaultNetwork: "polygon_amoy",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    polygon_amoy: {
      url: NEW_API_URL_KEY,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      gasLimit: 8000000, // Adjust this value as needed
    },
  },
};

I can't understand what the issue is. Can anyone please help me with this?
